# How to use TDS sensor with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, sensors

I am making a project for the greenwave competetion, but everywhere online it says that only with arduino you can use TDS sensor. I want to use with raspberry pi..
(im using thingspeak to record the response.)
I am actually using tds sensor, ph sensor, EC sensor, temperature sensor for this project. Is it possible to use all these sensors?

TDS sensor means Total Dissolved Solvents sensor.

Comment: Which sensor do you mean exactly? I've worked with many sensors, but "TDS" doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: You can hook up many sensors to RPi, but the TDS that works with Arduino has analog output. RPi doesn't have ADC converter onboard, so you would need to buy an extra ADC converter with I2C or SPI interface that preferably has a library for RPi already written.

Comment: TDS sensor means Total Dissolved Solvents sensor.